# Error when parse json in swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I want to get data from website by using JSON in my app. But the problem is that when I try to get the value of key ["posts"] in the JSON data, the error appears.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://bongdavn.com/category/du-lieu/?json=1")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data : Data?, urlResponse : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in
    if error != nil {
    }

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String : Any]
        let post = json!["post"] as! [String : Any]
        print(post)
        let content = post["content"] // error show from here.

        print(content)
        // the compiler show nil instead of value of "content"

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.TableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Catch the error : \(error)")
    }
}
.resume()
```

Here is my json data:

```
{  
   "status":"ok",
   "post":{  
      "id":121,
      "type":"post",
      "slug":"epl-england-premier-league-anh",
      "url":"http:\/\/bongdavn.com\/epl-england-premier-league-anh\/",
      "status":"publish",
      "title":"[EPL] England Premier League &#8211; Anh",
      "title_plain":"[EPL] England Premier League &#8211; Anh",
      "content":"<p>West Ham <strong><span class=\"hom\">1<\/span>\u00a0&#8211;\u00a0<\/strong><span class=\"awy\"><strong>1<\/strong>\u00a0<\/span>Leicester|||Crystal Palace\u00a0<strong><span class=\"hom\">2<\/span>\u00a0&#8211;\u00a0<\/strong><span class=\"awy\"><strong>1<\/strong>\u00a0<\/span>Stoke|||,
      "date":"2017-11-29 09:44:13",
      "modified":"2017-11-29 09:44:16",
      "categories":[  ],
      "tags":[  ],
      "author":{  },
      "comments":[  ],
      "attachments":[  ],
      "comment_count":0,
      "comment_status":"open",
      "custom_fields":{  }
   },
   "previous_url":"http:\/\/bongdavn.com\/bundesliga-dortmund-schalke\/"
}
```

Here is the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x109b9c328) to 'NSDictionary' (0x109b9cf58).
>   2017-11-29 22:45:19.764169+0700 BongDa[713:17684] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x109b9c328) to 'NSDictionary' (0x109b9cf58).
>   (lldb)

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: let content = post["content"]  from here. Please help me

Comment: Update your question with the output of `print(post)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json posted is wrong, according to what I get from the url, there is an array `posts`, so you can do something like:

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String : Any]
    let posts = json!["posts"] as! [[String: Any]] // posts is an array
    let post = posts.first! // get the first here, or according to your need
    print(post)
    let content = post["content"]
    print(content)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.TableView.reloadData()
    }
}
catch {
    print("Catch the error : \(error)")
}
}
.resume()
```

Comment: But the OP claims that the line `let post = json!["post"] as! [String : Any]` is working.

Comment: @rmaddy In my answer the json is different.

Comment: @ThànhTrungNguyễn If this works then everything in your question is wrong. This code will not work with the JSON you posted. And JSON this code works with would cause your code to crash on a different line. Please update your question properly so that this answer makes sense to your issue.

Comment: @maddy : thanks for your comment. i will fix it. Thanks alot